# Optimal way to fund all test accounts with ERC20 tokens

Tags: ethereum, solidity, hardhat

Curious to see how some of you are funding test accounts with ERC20 tokens?

The only practical way I've found is to individually call `token.transfer(someAddr, someAmt)` 20 times. I've been unsuccessful trying to implement a map function.

Answer (score 0):

Just the standard transfer call is good enough even over RPC as long as the tx object satisfies the transaction queue conditions i.e gas, gas price, nonce.

Here is one [tool](https://github.com/chaintool-py/chaind-eth) we use internally to do tens of thousands of ERC20 airdrops. It is mostly undocumented, but the little documentation can give you an idea on how to use it.